# Capture Font Resize Event in GWT

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, dom

In GWT, Is there a font resize event that I can listen to to capture events when the user changes the size of the font by Ctrl-Mouse Scroll/view -> Zoom?

Googled, and looked in StackOverflow. Found nothing. Apologies if it's been asked and I missed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code, it handles Control +/- and mouse scroll:

```
 Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
            public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
                  Window.alert("Resized");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You seem to be right. Wondering why my code isn't working then... I will check back later and provide updates (and accept answers:))...

Comment: Great. I found the problem in my handler. Thanks for the confirmation that this is the event I was supposed to look for. :)